# How to show a custom view dynamically based on time slots?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I am creating a Time table app in which I want to show events created. For this I have created layout in which I created a scroll view with a relative layout inside of it.  I made sure that the heights of these layouts were equal to the number of minutes in a day. This would make 1 hour = 60 minutes = 60 dp, which makes measuring the heights of events easier.

For events, I created a custom view that can display the start and end time of the event, as well as the event's title. The events I want to add to the relative layouts with a `layout_marginTop` property, whose value is equal to the starting time of the event in minutes from the beginning of the day.

For example, if I want to add a 1-hour long event at 01:30 AM, I would add the event view 90 dp from the top of the column with a height of 60 dp.

I know what i have to do but unable to implement it in code. Can anyone help please.

Now the layout looks like :[image]

Event view:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Start Time"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginStart="61dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="End Time"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginStart="87dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Title"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I am getting two events like this after following your ans :

[image]

How to check and get the events for different times?
And the height of event is not getting change..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your layout for time looks something like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView>
   <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/mytimetable">
   <!-- Your time blocks -->

   </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And you would like to add customviews of your events into this RelativeLayout at runtime with custom height and margin. You can do it like this with changing its [LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html)

```
//Getting your relative layout where you are going to place your events
ViewGroup dayplanView = (ViewGroup) layout.findViewById(R.id.mytimetable);

//Inflating your eventview but not adding it yet. Note that event_layout is your event layout resource.
View eventView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.event_layout, dayplanView, false);
//Getting its current layoutparams in order to change them
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) eventView.getLayoutParams();
//Setting its height (in pixels) (1h 30min)
layoutParams.height = dpToPixels(90);
//Setting topmargin (in pixels) (1.30am)
layoutParams.topMargin = dpToPixels(90);
//Adding layoutparams back to the view
eventView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
//Adding your eventview to the relativeview
dayplanView.addView(eventView);
```

Hereby I have created dpToPixels method to convert dp to pixels. It is a simplified version of [TypedValue.applyDimension](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TypedValue.html#applyDimension(int,%20float,%20android.util.DisplayMetrics)).
And it looks like this.

```
private int dpToPixels(int dp) {
    return (int) (dp * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
}
```

I hope this helped you. Goodluck with your app.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I have created this method in the fragment I used it in. It wasn't already there.

Comment: Thank you so much.. It helps.. Can you tell me how can I show this for different time slots using start time and end time?? @EgorDm

Comment: @user5669913 I would create a method in your fragment where you pass a inflater, a ViewGroup to inflate it in, start time and end time. Then you repeat the same process only you use start time to calculate the margintop and subtract starttime from endtime to get the height.

Comment: Sorry, i can't post long comments so i have put it on pastebin. http://pastebin.com/uTc3FmMi

Comment: I have put the whole class as a gist. It might be easier to use.
https://gist.github.com/EgorDm/13d4866492d80a94149f
@user5669913

Comment: Thank you so much for answer..Please check my edited answer..@EgorDm

Comment: though i have changed these values I am getting the events at same time slot.    float[] startTimes = new float[] {3f, 5f};
        float[] endTimes = new float[] {5f, 6f};

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101316/discussion-between-egordm-and-user5669913).